# Arraylist Seems Empty

Tags: java, android

I want to check the nickname is already taken or not data comes from firestorm and adds to the list but before if the statement the list seems empty and I can't control nickname is already taken or not here is my code I have no idea why does it seem empty.

**Here is my Code**

```
public class NickName extends AppCompatActivity {
private String userid;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseFirestore firestore;
EditText nickText;
String email;
private ArrayList<String> nicklist;
String nickforcheck;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nick_name);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    nicklist=new ArrayList<>();
    firestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    nickText=findViewById(R.id.nicktext);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
}

public void kayıt(View view){
    CollectionReference collectionReference=firestore.collection("Kullanıcılar ve Skorlar");
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(error!=null){
                Log.e("tag",error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            if(value!=null){
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                    Map<String,Object> userdata=snapshot.getData();
                    nickforcheck=(String) userdata.get("nick");
                    nicklist.add(nickforcheck);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    String nick=nickText.getText().toString();
    userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference documentReference=firestore.collection("Kullanıcılar ve Skorlar").document(userid);
    Map<String,Object> userdata=new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println(nicklist);
    if(nicklist.contains(nick)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bu Kullanıcı İsmi Zaten Mevcut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        userdata.put("nick",nick);
        userdata.put("email",email);
        userdata.put("skor",0);
        documentReference.set(userdata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                Log.d("Tag","Veri alındı"+userid);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("Tag","işlem başarısız"+e.toString());
            }
        });
        Intent intent=new Intent(NickName.this,Secimekrani.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You got empty nickList because ,all code outside addSnapshotListener will be executed before get the snapshot from firestore .so do all work ,once you successfully get snapshot.

```
  public void kayıt(View view){
    CollectionReference collectionReference=firestore.collection("Kullanıcılar ve Skorlar");
    collectionReference.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
            if(error!=null){
                Log.e("tag",error.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            if(value!=null){
                for(DocumentSnapshot snapshot:value.getDocuments()){
                    Map<String,Object> userdata=snapshot.getData();
                    nickforcheck=(String) userdata.get("nick");
                    nicklist.add(nickforcheck);
            
                 
                   String nick=nickText.getText().toString();
                  userid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

                   DocumentReference     documentReference=firestore.collection("Kullanıcılar ve Skorlar").document(userid);
            Map<String,Object> userdata=new HashMap<>();


  System.out.println(nicklist);
    if(nicklist.contains(nick)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Bu Kullanıcı İsmi Zaten Mevcut", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        userdata.put("nick",nick);
        userdata.put("email",email);
        userdata.put("skor",0);
        documentReference.set(userdata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                Log.d("Tag","Veri alındı"+userid);
                 
                 //once user data added in firestore ,finish your activity .
                 Intent intent=new Intent(NickName.this,Secimekrani.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.d("Tag","işlem başarısız"+e.toString());
            }
        });
        
    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
   
}
}
```

Comment: okey the if and else lines must be out of for loop then works thanks